# block ip address on website error code

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have blocked an IP address on my website using my htaccess.

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from 119.93.159.129
```

I am using the blocked IP address when I visit the website it display the apache installation page. Like this:

[image]

What is the error code when you block someone access to your website? And how do I redirect them to a specific page?

Comment: I would have expected a 403 error !?

Comment: I just tested this on my machine with `Deny from localhost`, and I get a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Add this `ErrorDocument 403     /403.html` to .htaccess or apache config and create that 403.html error page, your 403 page has wrong setup.